# What API entry points are available to write a task scheduler based on await pressure?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I was looking to write a [TaskScheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=netcore-2.1) that would prioritize the next [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netcore-2.1) to execute based upon how many points were awaiting upon it.

But I don't see anywhere that I can determine how many awaits are currently active for the Task. Starting off with the doubt that I'm the 1st person to want to do this, I'm assuming I'm just missing the API to obtain that data somewhere. Can somebody point me to it?

In lieu of that, I was thinking that maybe I could extend [Task](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs) to keep a count myself but ConfigureAwaiter() and GetAwaiter() are not virtual :(

I'm also open to "why not do this instead?" answers as I may be thinking about this all wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to do? And why do you care about the *count*? Most likely you *don't* need to implement anything. Higher level libraries and classes like PLINQ, Dataflow (eg  ActionBlock<T>) can control parallelism by specifying a Degree-of-parallelism parameter. As for documentation, there are a lot of examples and articles from 2010-2012. It's far easier to use a higher-level library though, so there's not a lot of interest in custom task schedulers.

Comment: It is at least an unusual requirement, since the majority of tasks in your typical async code base are awaited only once. Per Panagiotis, consider if one of the higher-level libraries wouldn't suit your needs better -- if you have a code base that creates "choke points" where execution of a lot of parallel work has to wait on some other data becoming available, you probably want to make this explicit in your declarations, not leave it implicit depending on how many continuations happen to be scheduled.

Comment: We are lazy loading object graphs in the background because the files/graphs are quite large. (Serialized in JSON). If someone tries to access fields on an object that hasn't been fully loaded, I want to await until the load is complete. However, if I have many loads pending, I want to prioritize the load that will unblock the object being accessed.

Comment: It's a bit more work (since it'll involve code generation or proxies), but you could make it so your object classes keep track of how many times they've handed out a `Task` that awaits their complete serialization, and base scheduling on that. Even so, it's worth considering if this is all really worth it. Assuming you're not doing this for fun and you have an actual performance/responsiveness bottleneck you may find *less* parallelism improves this case, as in, making dependencies more coarse grained and not trying to track access to every individual field/object asynchronously.

Comment: Alternatively, if you really think counting continuations is the best approach and you don't mind icky reflection, you can read the `m_continuationObject` private field, though you'd have no recourse to complain if that broke in the next release. `static class TaskExtensions { readonly static FieldInfo m_continuationObject = typeof(Task).GetField("m_continuationObject", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic); public static int GetContinuationCount(this Task t) => m_continuationObject.GetValue(t) switch { List<object> l => l.Count, { } => 1, null => 0 }; }`. (Use at own risk.)